# Pasar a otra pagina una vez que el formulario se ha validado

Tags: javascript, html, css

soy nuevo por aqui, asi que perdon si cometo algun fallo a la hora de realizar la pregunta.
La cosa es que tengo una pagina que simula un checkout, y tiene un js que cuando el formulario cumple una sola condición debería enviarse y cambiar a otra pagina.

Aquí esta el código del js:

```
  function valida_envia(){
    //valido el nombre
    if (document.fvalida.nombre.value.length==0){
           alert("Tiene que escribir su nombre")
           document.fvalida.nombre.focus()
           return 0;
    }

    //el formulario se envia
    alert("Muchas gracias por enviar el formulario");
    location.href = "../html/fbi.html";
    document.fvalida.submit();
    }
```

El caso es que lo envía, pero no me cambia de pagina, alguna idea de que puede estar pasando?

Comment: `document.fvalida.submit();` estaría previniendo el redirect

Answer (score 1):

Lo que tienes ahí es un comportamiento bastante anómalo, yo al leer tu código pensé que iba a entrar en esta línea `location.href = "../html/fbi.html";` te iba a redirigir a esa página y nunca se iba a ejecutar el submit

Pero como tu bien dices eso no ocurre, yo podría apostar que en el action del form tienes la misma página. Por ejemplo, digamos que tengo un `index.php` y en él tengo

```
<form id="fvalida" action="index.php">
```

El monitor de Red me muestra que
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se ve en la imagen se realiza la redirección, pero el servidor al devolver la petición vuelve a cambiar la página.

La solución que para mi es la "mas correcta" es que el servidor te responda con un redirección luego del submit.

En PHP sería

```
header("Location: ../html/fbi.html");
```

En ASP.net

```
return Redirect("../html/fbi.html");
```

Por otro lado, tu validación en posible realizarla con el atributo `required`

```html
<form>
 <input  required />
 <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```